# Display line in transactional e-mail if payment method is

Tags: email, email-templates, transactional, transactional-mail

I want to display a line only when the customer selects payment method checkout money order.
When a customer select money order as payment method, I want to display a `<li>` additional line to the transaction e-mail.

If the customer selects an other payment method, the additional `<li>` should be hidden.

I tried this code, but that does not work:

```
{{depend order.getPayment().getMethod() == "checkmo"}}
    <li>payment check</li>
{{/depend}}
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case you can mange this by handler.

### Use Handler:

### Create handler and define it at layout file:

`create a handler` and using this handler rendered a phtml file .
On `local.xml` at `app/design/frontend/YOUR_PAackage/YOUR_template/layout` define handler.

**Layout file code like:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
<!-- add new handler -->
        <amit_customer_addhan>
            <block type="core/template" name="addNewLi" template="sales/showcheckmo.phtml" />
        </amit_customer_addhan>
    </layout>
```

### Call this handler at email template

Then `on email html call this handler(locale/YourLANG/template/email/)`

```
{{layout handle="amit_customer_addhan" order=$order}}
```

**phtml file code:**

Then on `phtml file` put code like to `show extra li`

```
  <?php if($this->getOrder()->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=='checkmo'):?>
      <li>payment check</li>
     <?php endif;?>
```

Edit: location of `phtml file` is:
 `app/design/frontend/YOUR_PAackage/YOUR_template/template/sales/`

### OR: Without call of handler:

call a block file without layout handler and ans parameter for

```
 {{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='sales/showcheckmo.phtml' order=$order}}
```

In this case,need set to  `mangento area` as `frontend` as phtml file calling from here

Comment: Hi Amit, where can I find the file showcheckmo.phtml or where do I need to create it?

Comment: updated,please check

Comment: Tried it, but that does not work. The line is not displayed inside the e-mail.

Comment: Try to put some static content on phtml. And CKD the text comming  or not

Comment: No also with static content it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ok, i will check and let you know..

Comment: Got it! I use this line in my e-mail and that works {{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='sales/showcheckmo.phtml' order=$order}}

Comment: thanks.but i will check why handler is not call

Answer (score 0):

```
order.getPayment().getMethodInstance().getCode() == 'banktransfer'
```

Comment: Tried that, but that did also not work :(

Answer (score 0):

I'l try to answer on your initial question - how to use directive with condition. For debug I use xDebug. And in my opinion its very hard to debug emails. In that case I show you an example with the same structure in another part of magento.

On sales/order/view there is same structure. The address output structure determined in `Mage/Core/etc/config.xml` in `default/customer/address_templates/text`.

Our task will be add any condition to show or not to show 'company name'.
Directives such as **var**, **depend**, **if** parse in `Varien_Filter_Template` in method **filter($value)**. In this method there is iteration of all $constructions (if/depend/var) and every $construction used in this call:

```
$replacedValue = call_user_func($callback, $construction);
```

For each if/depende/var there is its own method. Lets look at `public function ifDirective($construction)`

```
public function ifDirective($construction)
{
    if (count($this->_templateVars) == 0) {
        return $construction[0];
    }

    if($this->_getVariable($construction[1], '') == '') {
        if (isset($construction[3]) && isset($construction[4])) {
            return $construction[4];
        }
        return '';
    } else {
        return $construction[2];
    }
}
```

Now lets look at protected method _getVariable. I'd like to draw your attention on one row:

```
} elseif (isset($stackVars[$i-1]['variable']) && $stackVars[$i-1]['variable'] instanceof Varien_Object) {
```

and look at the comment below:

```
// If object calling methods or getting properties
```

So to make condition our $stackVars should be an object and be an instace of Varien_Object (most of models extends from Mage_Core_Model_Abstract, which extends from Varien_Object). Lets climb a few steps above. We need to add to stackVars and object.

In my example in class **Mage_Customer_Block_Address_Renderer_Default** magento calls method filter($value), which I mentioned above.

---

### Here I provide a solution. Warning! This solution is not very clean. It's purpose to show magento behavior. Please do all rewrites yourself.

```
public function render(Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract $address, $format=null)
{

    //parsing $data array

    $formater->setVariables($data);

    $format = !is_null($format) ? $format : $this->getFormat($address);

    return $formater->filter($format);
}
```

In this method we will add an order object to $data array. According to my task lets add order object to this array. Do it before '$formater->setVariables($data);'

```
$data['order_object'] = $address->getOrder();
```

After this magento will parse this object and call any it's method. For example we add new method getPaymentOutput(). Put simple functionality into Order class:

```
public function isPrinted()
{
    if ($this->getPayment()->getMethod() == 'checkmo') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and only after that we make changes in xml directive with this:

```
{{if order_object.isPrinted()}}{{var smth}}<br />{{/if}}
```